# import Fabric in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the latest version of eclipse v23 and I have successfully install Fabric in eclipse , but I have faced problem in importing it where twitterauthconfig cannot be resolved to a type and other thing related to fabric can't be resolved also. 
I have tried to refresh project but it does not work.

Dose anyone face same problem? 
eclipse is sucks.

[my library folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0LNd.png)

[This is my project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX5yc.png)

Comment: better if you use `Android Studio`

Comment: @Mariam Have you got it working?

Comment: I switched to android studio and it's working , seems there is something wrong with eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the buildpath of kit-libs.

Below are the steps :

1) Right click on your project

2) Select Build path > Configure build path

3) Add jar files from your kit - libs in libraries folder and check all the jars in order and export tab.

This is how you can resolved your problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: where we can I get kit-libs? I couldn't find it

Comment: Whenever you import fabric to your project it will automatically included in your project

Comment: So you din't have properly configure fabric into your project